# In Typescript, what is the preferred method to unset/reset a numeric property: Undefined? Empty? Null?

Tags: typescript, null, numbers

I'm not new to JS but new TS. Google-fu has not answered this for me. Interested what ya'll have to say. Use case: I have a score object with multiple properties, including two actual score values each typed number. Once a quiz is taken different messages are generated depending on which scores have answers (and their values) If you restart the scores are reset.

What should I init & reset these properties to be (and consequently test) so that A. I can increment them. B. I can test later if they've been touched.

The obvious answer is 0 - but 0 is a valid result in both quizes.
My next inclination is Null, but in JS Null is actually object, and conflicts with the type.
I'm inclined to go with undefined, which tests negative and is type undefined.
Is that a bad idea? Is there a more robust/elegant option

I don't know if code is needed to illustrate this but here is a skeleton:

```
export interface ScoreObjTemplate {
    pol    : number,
    group  : string
    quiz   : string,
    choice : number,
    wVal   : number,
    fooScore ? : number,
    barScore ? : number
}

// a number of functions that iterate through questions for one or both quizes, adding positive or negative values based on choices 
this.myScore.fooScore = this.myScore.fooScore + myAnswer.Val

const myScore: ScoreObjTemplate;

if (this.myScore.fooScore) {
  generateMessage(this.myScore.fooScore);
}

if (this.myScore.barScore) {
  generateMessage(this.myScore.barScore);
}

generateMessage(score){
 switch(score)
   case < 0: 
     fooMsg = "lorem";
     break;
   case 0:
     fooMsg = "Ipsum";
     break;
   case >10:
     fooMsg = "Dolar";
     break;
   default:
     fooMsg = "Amet";
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties) is completely reasonable, so instead of `number` you have `number | undefined`.  Just be sure you check like `if (typeof this.myScore.fooScore !== "undefined")` or `if (this.myScore.fooScore != null)` instead of `if (this.myScore.fooScore)` because `0` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and you don't want to confuse `0` and `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I think `fooScore`, `barScore` can be structured as objects with their own internal state and you can extract any interaction with them to methods.

Please take a look at following example

```js
const myScore = {
  pol: 0,
  group: "",
  quiz: "",
  choice: 0,
  wVal: 0,
  fooScore: {
    active: false,
    value: 0
  },
  barScore: {
    active: false,
    value: 0
  }
}

function generateMessage(score) {
  let message = "";

  switch (true) {
    case (score.value < 0):
      message = "lorem";
      break;
    case 0:
      message = "Ipsum";
      break;
    case (score.value > 10):
      message = "Dolar";
      break;
    default:
      message = "Amet";
  }

  return message;

}

function setScore(score, value) {
  return {
    active: true,
    value: score.value + value
  }
}

function resetScore(score) {
  if (!score.active) {
    return score;
  }

  return {
    active: false,
    value: 0
  }
}

const random = (from, to) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from) + from);

function simulateQuiz() {
  const myAnswer = {
    Val: random(-2, 2)
  }

  switch (random(0, 4)) {
    case 0:
      myScore.fooScore = setScore(myScore.fooScore, myAnswer.Val);
      console.log('seting fooScore', myScore.fooScore)
      break
    case 1:
      myScore.barScore = setScore(myScore.barScore, myAnswer.Val);
      console.log('seting barScore', myScore.barScore)
      break
    case 2:
      myScore.fooScore = resetScore(myScore.fooScore);
      console.log('reseting fooScore');
      break;
    case 3:
      myScore.barScore = resetScore(myScore.barScore);
      console.log('reseting barScore');
      break;
  }

  let message = '';

  if (myScore.fooScore.active) {
    message = generateMessage(myScore.fooScore);
  }

  if (myScore.barScore.active) {
    message = generateMessage(myScore.barScore);
  }

  console.log(message);
}

setInterval(simulateQuiz, 1000);
```